# How to realize jQuery async treeview in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, treeview

I want to integrate an async treeview in PHP. Now i want to know how to generate a [source php](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/async.html) file with PHP.

Now my database structure is like this:

```
Create table School(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(50), 
primary key(id)
);
Create table Class(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50), 
school_id int(10), 
primary key(id), 
foreign key(school_id) reference School(id) on delete cascade
);
Student(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(50), 
class_id int(10),
primary key(id), 
foreign key(class_id) reference Class(id) on delete cascade
);



School -> Class -> Student
```

Now, i want to realize the treeview. Do you have any ideas of implementing it?

Thanks a lot.

Additional question: When i finish the treeview. If i click the items in the treeview, it will generate a result table by clicking. Do you know how to do that?

However, firstly i should finish the treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to (pseudo code):

```
$tree = array();
/**
 * the following line essentially executes the Query:
 * SELECT * from schools;
 * and returns all the rows in an array like 
 * $schools = Array(0=>array('id'=>1, 'name' => 'name'))
 */
$schools = $db->schools()->selectAll();

foreach($schools as $school)
{
   $schoolArr = array('text' => $school['name']);

   /**
    * Similar to the calls to school above except the query would be:
    * SELECT * from class where class.school_id = $school['id']
    * $school['id'] is the pk from the particular school record
    */
   $classes = $db->classes()->select("school_id = ?", $school['id']);
   $classesArr = array();
   foreach($classes as $class)
   {
      $classArr = array('text' => $class['name']);
      /**
       * Similar to the calls to school above except the query would be:
       * SELECT * from student where student.class_id = $class['id']
       * $class['id'] is the pk from the particular class record
       */
      $students = $db->students()->select('class_id = ?', $class['id']);
      $studentsArr = array();
      foreach($students as $student)
      {
          $studentsArr[] = array('text' => $student['name']);
      }

      $classArr['children'] = $studentsArr;
      $classesArr[] = $classArr;
   }

   $schoolArr['children'] = $classesArr;
   $tree[] = $schoolArr;
}

$jsTreeString = json_encode($tree);
```

Now obviously as you go through each loop you need to be assinging your other tree properties. then when youre all done just json_encode the array and echo it where i needs to be. At least thats how id work it. Note though, that you can probably do this without an individual query using some joins but i didnt want to get into all that - youll definitely wann explore that though if performance is at all an issue.

Comment: @prodigitalson, Thanks, you're definitely right. But, i don't know how to do that? What does your second line mean? Have you used any frameworks yet?

Comment: The second line is jsut some pseudo code to get the info from the db... you didnt specify which db extension and/or ORM you were using so i just made up some pseudo stuff assuming youd supplement thos calls with whatever you normally use to access your db. ill ammend with some detail...

Comment: @garcon: regarding your question on frameworks - I use Symfony, Zend, Agavi, and my own little mini framework depending onthe project. Most of my work is doen with Symfony or Zend. Normally i use Doctrine as my ORM in combination with one of those frameworks unless the data schema is super simple. In the past i used Propel - i actually still prefer Propel but it looks like Doctrine is the future so im trying to get more familiar.

Comment: @prodigitalson, WOW, You're so good at PHP. I should learn from you guys. And it's the first time i heard of Propel or Doctrine. I've got a lot to learn.

Comment: @garcon: Im not like a superstar or anything but im `competent++` :-)  Learning Propel/Doctrine isnt nessecarily an indicator of being good at php its just an indicator of being able to use those tools - same with frameworks. And its always better if you learn how to impleent things yourself first - then you have a better understanding of the language and whatever framework you use (or dont use).

Comment: @prodigitalson, thanks for your suggestions. It's pretty pratical. ;) 
I'm learning to use PHP for half an year, and it's difficult for me to use PHP or Framework fluently. It will be a long journey for me to master these tools.

Comment: @garcon: pas de problème... votre anglais est meilleur que mon français.. ;-) (im assuming french from your handle... but we knwo what assuming does...)

Comment: @prodigitalson, merci bien, lol ;)  i think your french is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this treeview to be done with jQuery I would suggest using [this plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/). You just need to run one JS function and it will work. And all your PHP part has to do is get data from db and generate a HTML that jQuery plugin can transform into treeview.

Comment: @RaYell, Thanks. I'm using this plugin, but i don't know how to generate a HTML. It's my problem now.